# TUF B550 Plus Wi-Fi: HiRes Audio Output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I'm trying to troubleshoot an audio issue where 96khz music doesn't get output correctly to an AV receiver through HDMI. My specs:

- I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 up an running in my rig.
- I have a TUF B550 Plus Wi-Fi motherboard that supports up to 192hkz audio output.
- Using HDMI for the connection.

In Ubuntu, I've tried the following:

- I have setup ALSA to pick up the correct card to use -- which in my case is `card3` by creating the file `/etc/asound.conf` according to [alsa's documentation](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Setting_the_default_device).
- `alsamixer` shows the correct card being used after a reboot.

However, when playing back the audio is limited to 48khz.

I'm at a loss here. Is there anything else I should be doing to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this on my own with a bit of research.

First, edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` with the following settings:

```
resample-method = soxr-vhq
default-sample-format = float32le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
avoid-resampling = true
```

Worth pointing out that the file comments with both `;` and `#`.

According to [this post](http://mclements.net/blogWP/index.php/2020/06/30/high-res-audio-on-ubuntu/), you probably don't need to use `soxr-vhq` and can settle for `speex-float-10`. Be sure to check the output of `pulseaudio --dump-resample-methods` to ensure that you are using an option that your system supports.

In the end, don't forget to restart `pulseaudio` to ensure the new settings are set using `pulseaudio -k`. You may need to reset the correct audio output in Ubuntu settings.

After this, glorious audio at 96khz and up was had without issues.